# Extracting the lines and arrows from matplotlib streamplot() (issues with scaling)

Tags: visualization, matplotlib, jupyter, plotting, ipython

My goal is to extract the coordinates of lines and arrows produced by plt.streamplot(), since I want to reuse them elsewhere. plt.streamplot() generates lines and arrows as objects of type LineCollection and PatchCollection. When I extract the coordinates of vertices from these objects, lines and arrows are not on the same scale (but they look aligned in the plot). Please help.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection, PatchCollection
    import numpy as np
    import pickle
    
    file_1 = open("x_and_v.pickle", "rb") 
    
    x_and_v = pickle.load(file_1)
    
    file_2 = open("stream_kw.pickle", "rb") 
    stream_kwargs = pickle.load(file_2)

    stream_result = plt.streamplot(*x_and_v, **stream_kwargs)
```

[image]

```
    line_coll, patch_coll = stream_result.lines, stream_result.arrows
    print(type(line_coll), type(patch_coll))
    
    # What transformations are used?
    
    print(line_coll.get_transform())

CompositeGenericTransform(
    TransformWrapper(
        BlendedAffine2D(
            IdentityTransform(),
            IdentityTransform())),
    CompositeGenericTransform(
        BboxTransformFrom(
            TransformedBbox(
                Bbox(x0=-5.509372024536133, y0=-7.944992256164551, x1=13.027548992919922, y1=11.767943889617921),
                TransformWrapper(
                    BlendedAffine2D(
                        IdentityTransform(),
                        IdentityTransform())))),
        BboxTransformTo(
            TransformedBbox(
                Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.9, y1=0.88),
                BboxTransformTo(
                    TransformedBbox(
                        Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=6.4, y1=4.8),
                        Affine2D().scale(100.0)))))))
    
    print(patch_coll.get_transform())

IdentityTransform()
    
    # Extract the lines and compute the bounds.
    
    line_vertices = [p.vertices for p in line_coll.get_paths()]
    x_lim_lines = [np.min([v[:, 0] for v in line_vertices]), np.max([v[:, 0] for v in line_vertices])]
    y_lim_lines = [np.min([v[:, 1] for v in line_vertices]), np.max([v[:, 1] for v in line_vertices])]
    print("Lines, x limits:", x_lim_lines)
    print("Lines, y limits:", y_lim_lines)

Lines, x limits: [-5.509372024536133, 13.027548992919904]
Lines, y limits: [-7.944992256164551, 11.767943889617936]
    
    # Note that these limits match the tranformation above.
    
    # Because the line data has a non-trivial transform, apply it:
    
    line_vertices = [p.transformed(line_coll.get_transform()).vertices for p in line_coll.get_paths()]
    x_lim_lines = [np.min([v[:, 0] for v in line_vertices]), np.max([v[:, 0] for v in line_vertices])]
    y_lim_lines = [np.min([v[:, 1] for v in line_vertices]), np.max([v[:, 1] for v in line_vertices])]
    print("Lines, x limits, with transformation:", x_lim_lines)
    print("Lines, y limits, with transformation:", y_lim_lines)

Lines, x limits, with transformation: [79.99999999999997, 575.9999999999995]
Lines, y limits, with transformation: [52.79999999999998, 422.40000000000026]
    
    # It's not clear why the stream plot doesn't use the transformed bounds.
    
    # Extract the arrow vertices and compute the bounds.
    
    vertices = [elem.vertices for elem in patch_coll.get_paths()]
    
    x_lim_arrows = [np.min([v[:, 0] for v in vertices]), np.max([v[:, 0] for v in vertices])]
    y_lim_arrows = [np.min([v[:, 1] for v in vertices]), np.max([v[:, 1] for v in vertices])]
    print("Arrows, x limits:", x_lim_arrows)
    print("Arrows, y limits:", y_lim_arrows)

Arrows, x limits: [-2437.2840820156075, 6456.394437113518]
Arrows, y limits: [-2674.2017274200357, 4002.588283293043]
    
    # Maybe the arrows need the same transform as the line to be on the same scale,
    # so I apply it here.
    
    patch_coll.set_transform(patch_coll.get_transform() + line_coll.get_transform())
    
    # Setting the transform doesn't change the data itself, we have to apply it below.
    
    # Extract transformed data
    transformed_vertices = []
    for path in patch_coll.get_paths():
        transformed_path = path.transformed(patch_coll.get_transform())
        transformed_vertices.append(transformed_path.vertices)
    
    # Get the tranformed bounds for arrows
    
    x_lim_arrows = [np.min([v[:, 0] for v in transformed_vertices]), np.max([v[:, 0] for v in transformed_vertices])]
    y_lim_arrows = [np.min([v[:, 1] for v in transformed_vertices]), np.max([v[:, 1] for v in transformed_vertices])]
    print("Arrows, transformed x limits:", x_lim_arrows)
    print("Arrows, transformed y limits:", y_lim_arrows)

Arrows, transformed x limits: [-64987.99349361962, 172983.8110651848]
Arrows, transformed y limits: [-49937.139704005014, 75246.72786954873]
    
    # No, the transformed arrows data are not on the same scale as the lines.
```